# Load string data that does not have quotes to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hue, beeline

I'm trying to load some test data to a simple Hive table. The data is comma separated, but the individual elements are not enclosed in double quotes. I'm getting an error due to this. How do I tell Hive not to expect varchar fields to be enclosed in quotes. Manually adding quotes to varchar fields is not an option since the input file I'm trying to use has thousands of records. Sample query and data below.

```
create table mydatabase.flights(FlightDate varchar(10),Airline int,FlightNum int,Origin varchar(4),Destination varchar(4),Departure varchar(4),DepDelay double,Arrival varchar(4),ArrivalDelay double,Airtime double,Distance double) row format delimited;

insert into mydatabase.flights(FlightDate,Airline,FlightNum,Origin,Destination,Departure,DepDelay,Arrival,ArrivalDelay,Airtime,Distance)
values(2014-04-01,19805,1,JFK,LAX,0854,-6.00,1217,2.00,355.00,2475.00);
```

The insert query above gives me an error message. It works fine if I enclose the varchar fields in quotes.

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 11:11 mismatched input '-' expecting ) near '2014' in value row constructor
```

I'm loading data using the following query

```
load data inpath '/user/alpsusa/hive/flights.csv' overwrite into table mydatabase.flights;
```

After load, I see only the first field being loaded. Rest all are NULL.

[image]

Sample data

```
2014-04-01,19805,1,JFK,LAX,0854,-6.00,1217,2.00,355.00,2475.00
2014-04-01,19805,2,LAX,JFK,0944,14.00,1736,-29.00,269.00,2475.00
2014-04-01,19805,3,JFK,LAX,1224,-6.00,1614,39.00,371.00,2475.00
2014-04-01,19805,4,LAX,JFK,1240,25.00,2028,-27.00,264.00,2475.00
2014-04-01,19805,5,DFW,HNL,1300,-5.00,1650,15.00,510.00,3784.00
```

Below is the output of DESCRIBE FORMATTED
[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you loading? Using insert into?

Comment: when you load data using insert statement you need to enclose string into quotes. However when you are loading from file, it's not required. show us how you are loading data from file

Comment: I edited the post to answer your questions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please provide full DESCRIBE FORMATTED mydatabase.flights output

Comment: Edited the post to add DESCRIBE FORMATTED screenshots

Comment: why are you posting text as a pictures? to make it difficult to someone who wants to copy and try to reproduce I guess

Comment: I posted my query and sample data in text format. The pictures are screenshots from Hue. I'm not sure what you're trying to copy from that.